# Bamboo VSTest Runner failing with "Could not find test result reports in the directory"

Tags: .net, bamboo, vstest, vstest.console.exe

VSTest itself seems to be succeeding and outputting the trx file in the expected directory, but Bamboo is failing to find and parse the results. The runner is configured as follows

[image: VSTest Runner Configuration]

The build log shows VSTest succeeding, and I can find and open the .trx file in the correct location, but Bamboo is stating no test cases were found.

```
02-Feb-2018 08:25:44    Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.5.0
02-Feb-2018 08:25:44    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
02-Feb-2018 08:25:44    
02-Feb-2018 08:25:44    /UseVsixExtensions is getting deprecated. Please use /TestAdapterPath instead.
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Starting test execution, please wait...
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Logger initialized. Logging to C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\5RESBQJP.LGW\BoostTestAdapter.dll.log
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestNumTest505
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestNumTest840
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestNumTest888
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestNumTest235
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestStrTest297
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Passed   TestStrTest283
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Total tests: 6. Passed: 6. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Test Run Successful.
02-Feb-2018 08:25:45    Test execution time: 0.6233 Seconds
02-Feb-2018 08:25:46    Results File: C:\Atlassian\Bamboo\temp\1517559944335-0\TestResults\Loki$_Loki_2018-02-02_08_25_45.trx
02-Feb-2018 08:25:46    Parsing test results under C:\Atlassian\Data\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\UTT-UTTB-JOB1...
02-Feb-2018 08:25:46    Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.
02-Feb-2018 08:25:46    Finished task 'Unit Testing' with result: Failed
```

This is using Bamboo 6.3.1, and a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the VSTest task does not properly detect testresults in the Bamboo working directory. I resolved the issue by placing the testresults in their own directory, which can be done by specifying the "Results Directory" field to any folder within the working directory.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks for the input, i actually meant to post this as a comment. Luckily i have found a way to work around the issue mentioned by DotEfekts. Hopefully this answer can help other people struggling with this issue.